# How do I MOVE a circle drawn in a subclass of UIView by overwriting the method "drawRect"?

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to figure out what i'm doing wrong but i just don't get it. Here is what i want to do:

I want to draw a circle somewhere on the screen of the iPhone and then i want the circle always to be displayed at the position where the user currently taps on the screen.
I started by creating a subclass of UIView and adding the following lines into the "drawRect" method:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

//Create the main view!

 CGContextRef mainscreen = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

 //Draw the dot
 //will be a circle cause rectangle is a square
 CGRect dotRect = CGRectMake(50, 80, 100, 100);
 [[UIColor blueColor] set];
 CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(mainscreen, dotRect);
 CGContextFillEllipseInRect(mainscreen, dotRect);

}
```

The appears just fine but now I have no idea how to make it move around on the screen I've tried several things and nothing worked.

Answer (score 1):

To draw the dot in a different location, change the origin of `dotRect`.  To figure out where to draw it, implement `-touchesBegan:withEvent:` and `-touchesMoved:withEvent:` and record the location where the touches are occuring.

Comment: and call setNeedsDisplay every time you change the origin.

Comment: yea but where exactly do i put the code? because for now i just implemented the three methods thouchBegan, touchEnded etc in the UIview subclass and then i put code into the viewControler class to make buttons do certain actions change label's text etc..And i did that by creating serveral IBOutlets for the objects i created in interface bulider. i don't really know how to access the circle through the view controller since it's not really an object created by interface builder!?

Comment: alright now i implemented the following: 
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
 center1 = [touch locationInView:self];
 [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

but its still not working......